# Need help to make a executable optimised sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql and I am struggling to form a query in optimized way:

Below is the table :[image]

Suppose the current financial year is 2020. I want to retrieve all the active employees along with the employees who left organization in between 1st Janauary, 2020 to 31st Decemeber, 2020 (2020-01-01 to 2020-12-31)(Inactive employee). An employee who doesn't have an date_of_leaving considered as an active employee. An employee who left the organization before 2020-01-01, should not be in the list.
Test cases:

1. If an employee's **date_of_joining = '2015-03-08'** and **date_of_leaving = 2019-12-31** --> Inactive employee. he should not be in query result.
2. If an employee's **date_of_joining = '2015-03-08'** and **date_of_leaving = null** --> active employee. he should be in query result.
3. If an employee's **date_of_joining = '2015-03-08'** and **date_of_leaving = 2020-12-31** --> Inactive employee. he should be in query result.
4. If an employee's **date_of_joining = '2015-03-08'** and **date_of_leaving = 2020-01-19** --> Inactive employee. he should be in query result.

I want to retrieve all the below fields :
contract_emp_id, offshore_emp_id, date_of_joining, date_of_leaving

can someone help me here to write an optimized sql query.

Comment: Do you have a working "unoptimizezd SQL query"?

Answer (score 0):

select * from table where date_of_leaving = NULL or date_of_leaving >= '2020-01-01'

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

`SELECT * FROM employee WHERE date_of_joining >= '08-March-2015' AND (date_of_leaving IS NULL OR date_of_leaving >= '01-January-2020');`

If your table size is too big then recommended to create non-clustered index on both column.

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage any indices you have on the table, but without that information this is good guess for efficiency:

```
SELECT contract_emp_id, offshore_emp_id, date_of_joining, date_of_leaving
FROM yourTable
WHERE IsActive = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT contract_emp_id, offshore_emp_id, date_of_joining, date_of_leaving
FROM yourTable
WHERE IsActive = 0
AND date_of_leaving >= '20200101'
```

Generally, I find `UNION ALL` to be handled better than `OR` by the optimizer.

However, you can try `OR` and see if it returns as quickly in your environment to save some lines of code if you prefer:

```
SELECT contract_emp_id, offshore_emp_id, date_of_joining, date_of_leaving
FROM yourTable
WHERE IsActive = 1
OR (IsActive = 0 AND date_of_leaving >= '20200101')
```

Answer (score 0):

The queries above are fine. They issue is whether you want to create an index for this one specific query.  Remember, the more indexes you have, the slower inserts/updates/deletes will be.

You want the keys to match the WHERE clause, the included columns to match the columns that you are pulling along for the ride.  You will likely want to modify this so that other similar queries can use this same index.

Here is the index I would recommend for this particular query.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_your_index_name]
ON [dbo].[Your_table] ([IsActive],[Date_of_joining])
INCLUDE ([contract_emp_id],[offshore_emp_id],[date_of_leaving])
```